Godot Blender IcoSphere import all messed up
I made a simple mesh in Blender by removing the default cube, adding an IcoSphere with 2 segments and removing half of the faces to make a bowl-like shape. Here's a screenshot in Blender

But when I now import it into Godot, It refuses to render the entire shape.

It seems only the faces which are on the outside of the mesh are rendered. And the generated CollisionShape (which is seen in the blue wireframe) also does not work as it should. I have an animation that makes the bowl move so it can pick up some things laying on the board. But as it moves, it simply passes through the other colliders, even though the collider of the bowl moves with the bowl

You've discovered that polygons in GPU rendering and triangle mesh collision physics are single-sided! If you want the inside of the bowl to be visible and collide, you need to double-up the polygons to have an inward-facing set, not just the outward-facing ones you have now.

This is indeed a new discovery. But then why does Blender still render it single-sidedly

Blender is 3D content creation software, so it's optimized for the needs of the content creator, who might want to see polygons on the far side of the object they're editing. Game engines are optimized for the needs of the player, who wants higher framerates by skipping rendering back-facing polygons (since under normal circumstances, those will be hidden behind the front-facing ones). In cases where the game developer wants players to see those polygons, we can use a double-sided material and pay the extra rendering cost, or just add polygons facing the direction we want.
